# I can't access my bitnami server using ppk

Tags: putty, bitnami, filezilla, winscp, cyberduck

Can someone help me fix this issue. I am connected few hours before but then when I tried to rename a folder using Putty I got disconnected and got this error.

***Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)***

I've tried the following solutions I got from the net.
- Re-gen private key
- Convert .pem to .ppk
- Move .ppk to other folder that all user has permission
- Use the ff username user,root,bitnami,ec2-user
- I tried it in Cyberduck, Winscp, filezilla, Putty

Thank you I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

bitnami developer here.

Depending on which platform you are working you could download again the .pem file in order to connect to your server. 
If you are working on any of our launchpads (https://aws.bitnami.com/, https://google.bitnami.com/, etc.) you have the option [image]

to download you .pem key, so it's not necessary to regenerate the key.

On the other hand, if you are working on the amazon ec2 console and you did not download the private key pair of your server in the moment of the creation of the machine you won't be able to connect to it again unless you create another machine.

In order to reconnect to the server you should download again the key files and use it with putty/filezilla/etc. Make sure you put the correct ip of the server or you won't have access to it.